# How to make my routes more efficient?

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, custom-routes

By making rewrite directives in **.htaccess** file I write my custom directives.

```
class Route {

    public $request_url;
    public $url_args;
    public $request_method;

    function __construct() {
        $this -> request_url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        $this -> url_args = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));
        $this -> request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    public function get($url, $callback) {
        if($this -> request_method == 'GET') {
            if($url == $this -> request_url){
                $callback();
            } elseif(strpos($url, ':')) {
                $new_url_args = explode('/', substr($url, 1));
                if(count($new_url_args) == count($this -> url_args)) {
                    $match = true;
                    $args = [];

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($this -> url_args); $i++) {
                        if($new_url_args[$i][0] == ':') {
                            $args[substr($new_url_args[$i], 1)] = $this -> url_args[$i];
                        } else {
                            if($new_url_args[$i] != $this -> url_args[$i]){
                                $match = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($match) {
                        $callback($args);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I initiated and added some routes as follows.

```
$route = new Route();

$route -> get('/', function() {
    echo "Welcome to DocsApp";
    die;
});

$route -> get('/test/sample', function() {
    echo 'tested';
    die;
});

$route -> get('/user/:id/:name', function($args) {
    echo  $args['id'] . '<br />' . $args['name'];
    die;
});
```

Everything is working fine.

But, every get function is calling instead of required one.
To prevent this, I call `die` at the end of success callback of matched route.

Is there any better way to call particular route function and preventing unnecessary calls?

Comment: Take a look here : https://github.com/noodlehaus/dispatch. You can use this library or look at the code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Olaf's answer I found some solution.
Adding `match_found` property to `Route` will help for preventing unnecessary calls.

```
class Route {

    public $request_url;
    public $url_args;
    public $request_method;
    private $match_found = false;

    function __construct() {
        $this -> request_url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        $this -> url_args = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));
        $this -> request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    public function get($url, $callback) {
        if($this -> match_found) {
            return;
        }
        if($this -> request_method == 'GET') {
            if($url == $this -> request_url){
                $callback();
                $this -> match_found = true;
            } elseif(strpos($url, ':')) {
                $new_url_args = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
                if(count($new_url_args) == count($this -> url_args)) {
                    $match = true;
                    $args = [];

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($this -> url_args); $i++) {
                        if($new_url_args[$i][0] == ':') {
                            $args[trim($new_url_args[$i], ':')] = $this -> url_args[$i];
                        } else {
                            if($new_url_args[$i] != $this -> url_args[$i]){
                                $match = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($match) {
                        $callback($args);
                        $this -> match_found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You already know, if the URL matches. I would just return `true` or `false` depending on the outcome, and decide on the return code, if you need to go further, e.g.

```php
public function get($url, $callback) {
    if ($this->request_method == 'GET') {
        if ($url == $this->request_url) {
            $callback();
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($url, ':')) {
            $new_url_args = explode('/', substr($url, 1));
            if (count($new_url_args) == count($this->url_args)) {
                $match = true;
                // ...
                if($match) {
                    $callback($args);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

```php
$route = new Route();

$match = $route->get('/', function() {
    echo "Welcome to DocsApp";
});

if (!$match) {
    $match = $route->get('/test/sample', function() {
                 echo 'tested';
             });
}

if (!$match) {
    $match = $route->get('/user/:id/:name', function($args) {
                 echo  $args['id'] . '<br />' . $args['name'];
             });
}
```